# Errors while installing php extenssion

Tags: php, centos, pear

I'm trying to install apc php extension for php 5.3.3 using the command **pecl install apc** but I get the following errors. I'm far from being server guru but as far as I can figure out this must be a php pear issue. Can anyone please give some advice how should I fix this problem? I use centos 5.7 vps hosting.

```
: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in PEAR/Dependency2.php on line 866

: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in PEAR/Dependency2.php on line 877

: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in PEAR/Dependency2.php on line 968

: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in PEAR/Dependency2.php on line 1032

: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in PEAR/Dependency2.php on line 1054

: Function split() is deprecated in OS/Guess.php on line 131

: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in OS/Guess.php on line 161

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735

: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 1044

: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 1053

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735
downloading APC-3.1.9.tgz ...
Starting to download APC-3.1.9.tgz (155,540 bytes)
.................................done: 155,540 bytes

: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in PEAR/PackageFile/v2/Validator.php on line 1616

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735

: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 1044

: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 1053

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735

Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CET/1.0/no DST' instead in PEAR/Validate.php on line 486

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735

: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 700

: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 709

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735

: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in PEAR/Builder.php on line 87

: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in PEAR/Builder.php on line 254
54 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
Enable internal debugging in APC [no] :
Enable per request file info about files used from the APC cache [no] :
Enable spin locks (EXPERIMENTAL) [no] :
Enable memory protection (EXPERIMENTAL) [no] :
Enable pthread mutexes (default) [yes] :
Enable pthread read/write locks (EXPERIMENTAL) [no] :
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.9
running: /tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9/configure --enable-apc-debug=no --enable-apc-filehits=no --enable-apc-spinlocks=no --enable-apc-memprotect=no --enable-apc-pthreadmutex=yes --enable-apc-pthreadrwlocks=no
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable APC support... yes, shared
checking whether we should enable cache request file info... no
checking whether we should use mmap... yes
checking whether we should use semaphore locking instead of fcntl... no
checking whether we should use pthread mutex locking... yes
pthread mutexs are supported!
checking whether we should use pthread read/write locking... no
checking whether the target compiler supports builtin atomics... yes
checking whether we should use spin locks... no
checking whether we should enable memory protection... no
checking for zend_set_lookup_function_hook... no
checking for sigaction... yes
checking for union semun... no
checking whether we should enable valgrind support... checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
yes
checking valgrind/memcheck.h usability... no
checking valgrind/memcheck.h presence... no
checking for valgrind/memcheck.h... no
checking for shm_open in -lrt... yes
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for g77... no
checking for f77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking for f90... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for ifc... no
checking for efc... no
checking for pgf95... no
checking for lf95... no
checking for gfortran... no
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... no
checking whether  accepts -g... no
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 32768
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.9/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.9/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.9/main -I/tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9/apc.c -o apc.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.9/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-root/APC-3.1.9/main -I/tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9/apc.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/apc.o
In file included from /tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:44:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:44:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:37: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:38: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'pcre'
/tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:393: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'pcre'
/tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9/apc.c: In function 'apc_regex_compile_array':
/tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:454: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'preg'
/tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:454: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'preg'
/tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:455: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'nreg'
/tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:455: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'nreg'
/tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9/apc.c: In function 'apc_regex_match_array':
/tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:487: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'preg'
/tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:487: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'preg'
/tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:488: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'nreg'
/tmp/tmpHdrv43/APC-3.1.9/apc.c:488: error: 'apc_regex' has no member named 'nreg'
make: *** [apc.lo] Error 1

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: If you don't need the most recent version, v3.1.3p1 is available in the base repository (in CentOS 6), and it was previously (CentOS 5) available in EPEL (v3.0.19). The package name is `php-pecl-apc`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is out of sync.

Try the following:

1. Make sure you have the latest version of pear by running  `pear upgrade pear`
2. From the command line, run `php -v` and make sure the version of PHP is what you are expecting.  You may have multiple PHP binaries on your system and the wrong one may be executing.

Comment: The first command just produces this error multiple times: : Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 8192 in /usr/share/pear/pearcmd.php on line 416. The second one says that php version is definitely 5.3.3 :)